# How to create a block matrix with centered elements

Tags: matrices, block

everybody. I was trying to compile a block matrix whose first line has a part that should be centered in that part of the line.

My closest attempt is the code:

```
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\hat{F}}_{11}^{(1)-1}
= 
\left[
\begin{array}{c|cc}
0 & \mathbf{1}_{10}& \\
\hline
\mathbf{1}_{10} 
 & 
\mathbf{M}_{11}^{(1)} & 
\mathbf{M}_{11}^{(1)\ast}\mathbf{\bar{I}}_{5} \\
&
\mathbf{\bar{I}}_{5}\mathbf{M}_{11}^{(1)H} &
\mathbf{\bar{I}}_{5}\mathbf{M}_{11}^{(1)}\mathbf{\bar{I}}_{5}\\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
```

which produce the result:

[image]

Ideally, the element $1_{10}$ should be centered in both, line 1 and column 1. Any trick?

Thank you!! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You could write `\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\mathbf{1}_{10}$} to make `$\mathbf{1}_{10}$` straddle columns 2 and 3.

Comment: @Mico: The `\multicolumn` needs to be _without_ the `$`.

Comment: Nice! Thanks @Mico. It works very good. That trick is as simple as useful.

Comment: @PeterGrill - Thanks for catching the mistake. I'll post a full answer to mention the correct setup.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}` to make the `\mathbf{1}_{10}` in the first row straddle columns 2 and 3. You may also want to load the `multirow` package and use an instruction such as `\multirow{2}{*}{$\mathbf{1}_{10}$}` so that the second `\mathbf{1}_{10}` straddles rows 2 and 3. (Incidentally, should that second `\mathbf{1}_{10}` term get a transpose symbol attached to it?)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}  % for `\multirow` macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathbf{F}}_{11}^{(1)-1}
= 
\left[
\begin{array}{c|cc}
0 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\mathbf{1}_{10}} \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{$\mathbf{1}_{10}$}
 & 
\mathbf{M}_{11}^{(1)} & 
\mathbf{M}_{11}^{(1)\ast}\bar{\mathbf{I}}_{5} \\
&
\bar{\mathbf{I}}_{5}\mathbf{M}_{11}^{(1)H} &
\bar{\mathbf{I}}_{5}\mathbf{M}_{11}^{(1)}\bar{\mathbf{I}}_{5}\\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```